# scala replace if else with state design pattern

Tags: scala, if-statement, state

Here is my if statement code in Scala:

```
package calculator

class Calculator() {
  var num = 0.0
  var count = 0

  def displayNumber(): Double = {
    num
  }

}

def handle(): Unit = {
    if (calculator.num == 0.0){
        calculator.num = number
      }
    else{
        calculator.num = calculator.num * 10 + number
      }
    }
```

How do I replace the if-else with state pattern?

Comment: Your code is missing some content. Is `calculator` a case class? Is `calculator.num` a `var` or `val`? Because one of them will cause your current code to break.

Comment: The `if` statement is completely redundant here, just do your `else` clause unconditionally. What is "state pattern" anyway?

Comment: @HarisNadeem hi I have editted my code.

Comment: @Dima What do you mean? Could you show me the example? I am confusing with the wording

Comment: @C.Lawrence example: `def handle() = { calculator.num = calculator.num * 10 + number }`
BTW, your code does not compile after you "edited" it: neither `calculator` nor `number` are defined. Also a closing brace is missing.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean State monad?

```
  import cats.data.State

  val number = 20.0

  case class Calculator(num: Double, count: Int)

  def state: State[Calculator, Unit] = for {
    calculator <- State.get[Calculator]
    _ <- State.set(if (calculator.num == 0.0) calculator.copy(num = number) else calculator.copy(num = calculator.num * 10 + number))
  } yield ()

  state.runS(Calculator(0.0, 0)).value // Calculator(20.0,0)
```